# Mystery 0 in Output of Pascal's Triangle Function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function in R that, given the `n`th row of Pascal's Triangle (in the form shown), it returns the `n+1`th row (in the same form).

I've written the function below and tested it for `n = 4`:

```r
pascal.tri <- function(n) {
  l <- length(n)
  for (i in 1:(l + 1)) {
    new.vec[i] <- choose(l, (i - 1))
  }   
  n[[l+1]] <- new.vec
  return(n)
}

n <- list(c(1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2, 1), c(1, 3, 3, 1))

pascal.tri(n)
[[1]]
[1] 1
    
[[2]]
[1] 1 1
    
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 1
    
[[4]]
[1] 1 3 3 1
    
[[5]]
[1] 1 4 6 4 1 0
```

But I keep getting that random 0 appended to the `new.vec` (and so in the list). I've gone through this line by line, making it edits here and there, and it won't go away.

I have no idea what's causing this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function gives another error: "Error in new.vec[i] <- choose(l, (i - 1)) : object 'new.vec' not found". This is because `new.vec` was not created before you use it within the scope of `pascal.tri`. By adding `new.vec = c()`, the error goes away.

```
pascal.tri <- function(n) {
       new.vec = c()
       l <- length(n)
       for (i in 1:(l + 1)) {
             new.vec[i] <- choose(l, (i - 1))
         }   
       n[[l+1]] <- new.vec
       return(n)
}

n <- list(c(1), c(1, 1), c(1, 2, 1), c(1, 3, 3, 1))

pascal.tri(n)
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 3 3 1

[[5]]
[1] 1 4 6 4 1
```

Not able to reproduce your other error

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't getting that error, for some reason. But, initializing new.vec in the function, indeed, fixed my issue, as well. So, thanks!

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude It could be that you already have a variable called `new.vec` in your global environment. So when the `pascal.tri` couldn't find that variable in the function scope, it searches for it in the global environment and finds it, hence, no error.